# F-Spot fails to load into Ubuntu 16.04.

Tags: f-spot

I have tried to download F-Spot into my PC that runs Ubuntu 16.04 and have failed. Have tried F-Spot from several sources without success. Any Ideas?

Comment: I answered your question, but if this solution fails please edit your question and provide the exact outputs and errors.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Am studying and trying to absorb it. As a non programmer this is a bit daunting.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm here to help – when you open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), type `uname -m` and hit Enter, what does it respond?

Comment: It shows: x86_64       (next line): george@george-MS-7592

Comment: OK, then you need the amd64 version, see my answer for the link. Just download and click the file, it should install f-spot automatically.

Comment: I went to f-spot.org It offered the latest version 0.8.2, Dec 19, 2010

Comment: clicked on "download". It offered "GNOME Archives". Clicked on "0.8/". That offered "LATEST-IS-0.8.2". Clicked on it. Got a full red screen in a grid pattern with mostly /00/ characters. Screen changed to gray after a few minutes. After a half hour got message "there was a problem  opening the file - "/tmp/mozilla_george0/LATEST-IS-0.8.2". There was never a chance to select amd_64 version.

Comment: You can use the (`.tar.gz`) files from http://f-spot.org/Download, however using a `.deb` package is simpler – [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/f-spot/download) has the right one, just choose a server in your vicinity on that website and it will offer you to download the `.deb`. Then just click it and the installation should begin.

Comment: How can one find the geographical locations? Some are clear but many are not. I'm near Washington DC. One has "gov" in it's ID. Would that be the DC area? What is "mirror"? A copy? I can't imagine a horizontally reversed image.

Comment: No, a “mirror” is just a download server who “mirrors” the file so that the load is not concentrated on one single server. Just pick one, it doesn't really matter. The file you download is the same for every mirror server.

Comment: OK! It looks like I've successfully downloaded F-Spot! It is a file in my home folder. A screen provides a button to install F-Spot but nothing seems to happen. I gave it 5 minutes or more. There is no indication of any activity after I clicked install. Used my search bar to see if F-Spot is really there and yes, it is. Also tried to click "open", but no response.

Comment: Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), type `sudo apt install ~/f-spot*.deb` and hit Enter, this will start the installation for sure.

Comment: I get:       Reading package lists.......Done  E: Unsupported file /home/george/f-spot.deb given on command line george@george -MS-7592:~$

Comment: You did forget the asterisk `*`, didn't you? ;)

Comment: I copied incorrectly in my comment to you, but included it correctly in my terminal input.

Comment: Type `sudo apt install ~/f-spot` and before hitting Enter hit Tab please, it will then enter the filename automatically, after that hit Enter.

Comment: I get:  Reading package lists....Done  E: Unsupported file/home/george/f-spot given on command line george@george-MS-7592:~$

Comment: Where did you download the file to? Apparently it's not in your home folder. Give `sudo apt install` the whole path.

Comment: It's in the home folder under "Downloads"

Comment: well then of course the command is `sudo apt install ~/Downloads/f-spot*.deb`

Comment: I got:  Some packages could not be installed. You may have requested an impossible situation, or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required  packages have not yet been created or been moved out of incoming. The following information may help resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies (gives a group of 3 subprograms).  Recommends dcraw but it is not going to be installed. E: unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: please solve this question by asking google

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the `.deb` package suitable for your system architecture: [i386](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/f-spot/download) or [amd64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/f-spot/download) (choose a mirror in your vicinity – your system architecture is shown by `uname -m`, where *x86_64* corresponds to *amd64*)
2. Open the file to install the package.

Alternatively you can download the [tar.gz archive](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/f-spot/0.8/f-spot-0.8.2.tar.bz2) and install it as explained here: [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030/507051)